# Number of full table scans

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, scan

I would like to see information on how many times has a table been fully scanned.
I was hoping for something like `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` but for table scans.
There is a method described at the blog [keepitsimleandfast](http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2011/11/how-to-find-table-scans-in-your.html), but I would rather get all scans since server started.

What I am looking for is also similiar to `pg_stat_all_tables.seq_scan` in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, that table will give you the answer you are looking for.  Just join onto sys.indexes to determine the type of index.  Tables are either Heaps or Clustered indexes, so a scan on that index type *is* a scan on the table.  See the example below, add any additional columns you are looking for.

```
SELECT S.name AS SchemaName
    , O.name AS ObjectName
    , I.name AS IndexName
    , I.type AS IndexType
    , I.type_desc AS IndexType_Desc
    , IUS.user_scans
FROM sys.objects AS O 
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON S.schema_id = O.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS I ON I.object_id = O.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS IUS ON IUS.object_id = I.object_id AND IUS.index_id = I.index_id
WHERE I.type IN (0,1) -- 0=HEAP, 1=CLUSTERED (table)
```

Comment: After checking it seems you're right, thank you.
Just add `AND IUS.object_id = I.object_id` in last join

Comment: Great query...just for fun I added in sys.partitions for rowcounts and (scans * rows) for measuring impact.